# Factorial program in android

Tags: android

Hey guys I know there are many java programs for the factorial of a number...but I am facing problem with android. Following is my code....Thanks

```
package com.droidacid.apticalc.aptitudes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.droidacid.apticalc.R;

public class AptiFactorial extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{
EditText number;
TextView answer;
Button calculate;

long factorial = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.apti_factorial);
    initialize();
    calcFactorial();
}
private void initialize() {
    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_apti_number);
    answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_apti_answer);
    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_apti_calc);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(this);
}
private void calcFactorial() {
    if (number.getText().toString().equals("")) number.setText("0");
    int num = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
    for(int i = 1; i<=num; i++){
        factorial = i * factorial;
    }

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    calcFactorial();
    answer.setText("Factorial of " + number.getText().toString() + " is : " +     factorial);

}

}
```

This is my code and I need to know a way around for setting the hint instead of 0, but if I remove `if (number.getText().toString().equals("")) number.setText("0");`

then getting NullPointerException...
Also on the first go its calculating correctly but If I calculate again then getting wrong answer. I think some loop issue because I am directly using the value of factorial.

Please help thanks

Comment: Android has a `hint` function, `number.setHint("Enter number to be factorialized :P")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget all that `equal` stuff, cover all basis and do it like this:

```
package com.droidacid.apticalc.aptitudes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.droidacid.apticalc.R;

public class AptiFactorial extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{
EditText number;
TextView answer;
Button calculate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.apti_factorial);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_apti_number);
    number.setHint("Enter number to be factorialized :P")
    answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_apti_answer);
    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_apti_calc);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private long calcFactorial() {

    long factorial = 1;
    try {
        factorial = Long.parseLong(number.getText().toString());
        for(int i=factorial-1; i>0; i--){
            factorial = i * factorial;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {}

    return factorial;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    answer.setText("Factorial of " + number.getText().toString() + " is : " + calcFactorial());
}
```

Comment: That is due to the limitations of the type `long`, if you really want to be able to compute larger numbers you may want to look at other variable types, for example: `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger`. Remember, you would only have to change the function `calcFactorial()` everything else should stay the same (as long as it is working :P).

Comment: now error on this line : factorial = BigInteger.parseBigInteger(number.getText().toString());      tried Integer etc but nothing worked

Comment: also now its not accepting BigInteger factorial = 1; In the initializing part

Comment: I haven't used either of `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger`, however I do believe you should use `BigDecimal` look through this library to see how to use it: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html , http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 0):

Do something like.

```
private void calcFactorial() {
    int num = 0;
    if (!number.getText().toString().equals(""))
          num = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
    for(int i = 1; i<=num; i++){
        factorial = i * factorial;
    }

}
```

Comment: Still like if i enter 5 its giving 120 as answer if I enter 6 its giving 86400

Comment: ok ...I got you .. just set the factorial = 1; at every click

Answer (score 0):

```
 Rather than using
(number.getText().toString().equals("")) number.setText("0");
Use
(number.getText().length==0) number.setText("0");
```

Comment: you have not reset the value of factorial to 1

when you clicks on the button at that time reset value to its value to 1

Answer (score 0):

```
** first go its calculating correctly but If I calculate again then getting wrong answer**
```

try like this

```
 private void calcFactorial() {
    factorial = 1;///Check out the line..
        int num = 0;
        if (!number.getText().toString().equals(""))
              num = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
        for(int i = 1; i<=num; i++){
            factorial = i * factorial;
        }

    }
```

You need to make sure variable factorial is reinitialise to 1 .. for getting factorial for next number..

Answer (score 0):

```
private void fact_isClicked(View view) {
        
        if(textField.length()>0){
        int ifac = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText().toString());
        int fact = factorial(ifac);
        
        tvsec.setText(String.valueOf(fact));
        textField.setText(ifac+"!");
        
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer! Your answer could be improved by fixing up the formatting of the code and providing some additional information about what the code does and how it answers the question. Links to references or other materials are also helpful for those with a slightly different use case.